# Machine Learning with Higher Level of Abstraction

Tags: machine-learning

I was wondering how you would make a machine learning algorithm think with higher levels of abstraction -- I can't seem to find any resources on this.

Say I trained a machine learning algorithm to recognize cats, using a dataset with 1000 labeled examples. Would I need to build a whole new algorithm and train it on 1000 new data points to recognize dogs, even though cats and dogs are kind of similar? Is there a way to do something where I feed the cat algorithm a few pictures of dogs (far fewer than 1000), and now it is able to detect dogs as well? It seems tedious to have to retrain an algorithm to do something very similar (which I have been doing so far).

Sorry if this question seems very elementary. I am very new to machine learning (haven't taken any classes or anything); I've only used very simple classification algorithms and basic tensorflow so far.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, actually what you're looking for is called **transfer learning** and its actually very common in deep learning and especially image recognition these days.

**Here's how transfer leraning works (intuitively):**

In terms of your example, you have a model that has learned very well to recognize cats. But in order for the model to be able to recognize if an image (note: the computer sees the image as an array of pixels, nothing more) is a cat or not, it first needs to be able to see simpler features (e.g. lines, curves, corners, circles). We call these **lower-level features**. By combining these features the model can now learn how to see **higher-level features**, or more complex shapes, possibly domain specific (e.g. eyes, ears, paws, tails). Now these high-level features are passed on to a simple classifier to tell us if it is a cat or not.

Now say we want to make a model that recognizes if an image is a dog or not. Normally we would have to train it from scratch, but do we really have to? Actually, **no**! We can use some of the *knowledge* learned from the cat model in order to make our life easier. Turns out that these low-level features (lines, edges, etc.) the cat model had to learn first are pretty much **generic** and can be used in any image recognition task! So we can use these low level features as they are, adapt the high-level ones and just fully train the classifier at the end. Thus with minimal training we have a model that can learn how to recognize dogs!

This whole concept becomes clearer once you take a look at the features:

[image]

At the bottom you can see the generic low-level features that can be used in any image related task. Then each model creates its own high-level features **from the low-level ones**. This means than once a model has learned to extract those, this knowledge can be passed to another model.

Besides reduced training time models can actually **benefit from the larger training set** the initial model was trained upon! Subsequently, as you stated, the second model **can be trained with less images** than the first!

**How is this done in practice?**

The easiest way to do this is to train a **Convolutional Neural Network** on the first task (in your case cats) and then train a second one **with the same architecture** on the second task (dogs). The trick is to **initialize the weights of the second model to the weights of the first**. Then you can select to possibly **freeze** the first layers of the model, because those correspond to low-level features that the model has already learnt to extract.

This procedure is actually so common that the **majority** of image recognition models trained nowadays have their weights initialized from another pre-trained model.

**Any examples?**

The first time I saw this was during the [Cats vs Dogs kaggle competition](https://www.kaggle.com/c/dogs-vs-cats), where one of the top ranked contestants just downloaded the weights of a model pre-trained on the ImageNet dataset and then trained the model for like 5 minutes (btw this procedure is usually called **fine-tuning**).

Comment: Can you explain where the terminology "low-level", "high-level" comes from? Is it related to humans?

Comment: I'm not sure if the terminology comes or not from the human visual system, but both humans and CNNs have a hierarchical organization of their processing of visual systems, so the terms "low-level" and "high-level" could be applicable to both.

Answer (score 0):

There's are so many ways to answer a question like this.

You need to get clear on what you want your "machine learning algorithm" to do.

Do you want to:

- Detect cats only?
- Detect cats & dogs?
- Detect cats with a high level of accuracy (or confidence)?
- Detect cats & dogs very quickly (ie speed over accuracy)

What have you tried?  It might appear tedious to retrain, but if it works - then does it matter?  Take a "self driving car" algorithm.  Society is not interested how tedious it might be, if its unsafe (or doesn't work).

Another example is computer chess.  In the 70's & early 80's, it was all about brute force.  "What is the *best* move I can find in a short period of time.

But then the algorithms got smarter.  They learnt about opening moves, mid game and end game strategies.

The saying "when you're holding a hammer, everything looks like a nail" applies here.

If you are still unsure, then research the use cases.  Ie what sort of algorithm could you use to detect a cat?  Which is the best?  (how do you measure "best"?  Speed, efficiency, accuracy?)